# How to extract TLS meta-data from a pcap using Scapy

Tags: python, ssl, scapy, tls1.3

I'm trying to write a Python script to extract TLS 1.3 meta-data(record length, record type...) from a pcap using Scapy. 
I'm facing two major difficulties:

- I'm unable to parse multiple TLS messages in one packet. For example, the packet that contains the ServerHello message contains also other TLS messages but I'm able to extract only the first message.
  [Scapy show only information related to the first message in the packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa8ZK.png)
  [But this packet contains 3 TLS messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oT1J.png)
- Some TLS application data messages don't show any meta-data (type, version, length).

Comment: Hi alajeb, and welcome to SO. Please add the relevant section of your Python script or at least a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable example as stated on the [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the documentation.